# Get dataframe result to a variable

Tags: python, dataframe

How to get the value only from a dataframe from a query?

I have this dataframe

```
In [78]: dfSYS1vsPHDTags
Out[78]:

            Machine   System 1 Description   Segment ID  Converted PHD Tag
0            C-1185   Compressor Speed       54322       PI370
1            C-1185   Comp O/B Horz          54364       PI371
2            C-1185   Comp O/B Vert          54365       PI372
```

Applying this query

```
In [95]: dfSYS1vsPHDTags['Converted PHD Tag'][dfSYS1vsPHDTags['Segment ID'] == int(54322)]
Out[95]:

0    PI370
Name: Converted PHD Tag, dtype: object
```

I need to put in a variable just the **Converted PHD Tag** value **`PI370`**

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's not clear what you want the new column to have in it.  Creating new columns in Pandas isn't hard, you just assign to it, e.g. `df['new'] = ...`  Maybe expand your example above to show actual values in the new column.  Or tell us how it should be calculated and what you tried already.

Comment: @Jeff you are right is very simple I was over complicating what I needed. I changed the question, if you can help me with this one very appreciated.

Comment: Your code line doesn't look like it would run.  Can you make this reproducible using toy data?

Comment: Hi @Jeff I just changed it

Comment: Just add [0] at the end? `dfSYS1vsPHDTags['Converted PHD Tag'][dfSYS1vsPHDTags['Segment ID'] == int(54322)][0]`

Comment: how do I get the index for that row dynamically?

Comment: That depends on the query. If the query returns a single item you can use [0], otherwise you'll need another criterion to decide which value you want - or you'll need to use the returned array.

Comment: Always the result will be one record but different index every time, in that example was zero but can be anything.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I added the values `dfSYS1vsPHDTags.loc[dfSYS1vsPHDTags['Segment ID'] == int(54322), 'Converted PHD Tag'].values[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer for the question

Using the Dataframe.loc

```
dfSYS1vsPHDTags.loc[dfSYS1vsPHDTags['Segment ID'] == int('54322'), 'Converted PHD Tag'].values[0]
```